# Vhdl Type mismatch error

Tags: vhdl

I am having a type mismatch error, but all values are of same type std_logic.
Here is the code

Nx, Ny - generics

ipx - an input port vector

tempx, tempz - signals

> ipx : in std_logic_vector(Nx-1 downto 0);
>   .......
>   signal tempx : std_logic_vector(Ny-1 downto 0) := ipx(Nx-1 downto Nx-Ny); (Signal initialisation)
>   signal tempz : std_logic_vector(Ny-1 downto 0);
>   ............
>   tempx <= (Ny-1 downto 1 => tempz(Ny-2 downto 0), 0 => ipx(a-1));

error : Error (10381): VHDL Type Mismatch error at ArrayDivider.vhd(53): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_ulogic", the type of the target expression 
(Error on last code line of tempx)

But ipx and tempz both are std_logic vectors so, where is the type mismatch here????
Please give me some solution

I have tried on using the concatenate operator & also but it gives me another error related to top level hierarchy and 'can't resolve multiple constant drivers of tempx[0]' !!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

`error : Error (10381): VHDL Type Mismatch error at ArrayDivider.vhd(53): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_ulogic", the type of the target expression`

And indeed, `tempz(Ny-2 downto 0)` is not a std_ulogic but a vector.

The problem is that named association does not identify slices of a vector but individual elements; you can't use it to assign one slice of one vector to a slice of another vector.

Instead, use the concatenation operator `&`,

```
tempx <= tempz(Ny-2 downto 0) & ipx(a-1);
```

Your post implies that concatenation produces other errors; feel free to add these to the question.

EDIT :

```
>Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net 
>"tempx[0]" at ArrayDivider.vhd(44) (on the line of initialing >tempx)
```

Again this tells you what is wrong. This error is almost certainly there in both versions of the design, but the original error just hides it. Find the two drivers for tempx(0) and eliminate whichever is the wrong one. You haven't posted enough of your code to make it clear what's going on so that is up to you. If you're using Modelsim, the "drivers" command will identify all the drivers on a signal.

If you need to initialise tempx to the input signal and then later drive it with another signal, you must select between the two signals - for example:

```
tempx <= ipx(Nx-1 downto Nx-Ny) when <some condition>
         else tempz(Ny-2 downto 0) & ipx(a-1);
```

Most likely, fixing this error will also eliminate the "hierarchy" error; which is basically "something went wrong earlier so compilation cannot be completed".

Comment: Thanks for support and your interest to solve my errors...:)
I have tried concatenation also.........
But that gives me 2 errors...........

>Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net >"tempx[0]" at ArrayDivider.vhd(44) (on the line of initialing >tempx)

>Error: Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page that explains the concept of named association vs. positional association quite nicely. Notice that the example shows use of both association methods using the bit_vector type.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/aggregat.html

As you have noticed, VHDL returns a bit_vector when you perform named association on an std_logic vector. This causes a type mismatch if you try to assign the result to a std_logic_vector.

One option is to convert between bit_vector and std_logic_vector using TO_BITVECTOR and TO_STDLOGICVECTOR. These are defined in the ieee.std_logic_1164 library, and the syntax is decribed here:

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/PackageSTD_1164.html

Doing this feels like jumping through unnecessary hoops, but it should work.  Good luck!